# How can I use Zend_Dom_Query to get meta data

Tags: php, zend-framework, web-scraping, zend-dom-query

Using Zend_Dom_Query, I would like to retrieve meta data out of an HTML string.

to retrieve links you can simply query like so:

```
$results = $dom->query('a'); //Where $dom is your html string
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with meta

```
$results = $dom->query('meta'); //doesn't work
```

How can I retrieve meta data and then filter by its 'property' attribute?

An example of what I'm looking for:

```
               public function meta($dom)
{
    $results = $dom->query('meta'); //This is not a correct query (does anyone have an alternative?)
    $links = array();
    foreach ($results as $index => $result) {
        if ($result->getAttribute('property') == 'title') { //find <meta property="title"
            echo $result->getAttribute('content') . '<br />'; //echo the content attribute of the title
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

This code would work once the query is correct. However I would like to take it a step further and query directly for `<meta property="title" content="This is the Title" />` instead of retrieving all meta and looping around to get the right one.

Any help with either getting all meta data using zend_dom_query or (more importantly) querying to receive only the meta data where property == title would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ***meta tag*** in not a *valid CSS selector* so you have to use the `$dom->queryXpath($xPathQuery)` method instead of `$dom->query()`.

maybe something like:

```
$dom->queryXpath('/html/head');
```

I'm not sure of the exact query string to use, but this is the idea.

[Zend_Dom_Query Theory of Operation.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.dom.query.html#zend.dom.query.operation)

Answer (score 0):

### if you have got url try this:

---

> > $metatagarray = get_meta_tags($url);
> >         if (!empty($metatagarray["keywords"]))
> >            $metakey = $metatagarray["keywords"];
> >         if (!empty($metatagarray["description"]))
> >            $metadesc = $metatagarray["description"];